# How to pass these array location attribute in to setState and and display the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I want to access to these array location attributes and How to pass loaction to the setstate and display them inside the return state (react functional component used)**

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `response.data.exsitingSupplierDetails` is an Array of `length = 1`, you can access the `location` like this:

`response.data.exsitingSupplierDetails[0].location`